# How to limit access to POST request over HTTPS for a single a file in Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, apache-config

I have limited access to a file `service.php` located in `/var/www/sample` to HTTPS with following code:

```
<Directory /var/www/sample>
        <Files service.php>
                SSLRequireSSL
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

Now, I would like to limit the access only for POST requests. There is a [`<Limit>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limit) directive that should do this but how should I combine it with the above configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use mod_rewrite and add this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/service.php # if service.php requested
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$ [NC] # and if its not post
RewriteRule .* - [F] # then block access (403 forbidden)
```